# Web Scraping w/ Selenium & BS4 - Not scraping from all of the URLs that I want

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Not entirely sure of what is going wrong here, but my code seems to work perfectly fine, but after a certain period of time the scraping stops and I'm unsure of what to do.

Website: https://www.rew.ca/

Background: I want to scrape all of the individual features of real estate listings. All of the URLs are based on the hrefs scraped from each page of the website and seems to all work perfectly fine and are all unique URLs. Using the "list_price" as an example, the code below scrapes all of the list_prices until it randomly stops at any given number (ex. seen it stop after 11, 23, 7, etc. different URLs are used) yet all of the values that are scraped were correct.

Code:

```
# Create arrays for all of the information that will be scraped from the website
property_sizes = []
descriptions = []
list_prices = []
bedrooms = []
bathrooms = []
property_types = []
lot_sizes = []
years_built = []
titles = []
styles = []
features = []
amenities = []
appliances = []
communities = []
days_on_rew = []

# Initialise all of the features as NaN to keep the indexing correct when appending to the arrays
property_size = None
description = None
list_price = None
num_bedrooms = None
num_bathrooms = None
property_type = None
lot_size = 0
year_built = None
title = None
style = None
the_features = None
the_amenities = None
the_appliances = None
community = None
days_on_website = None

# Use for loop to index through each url and scrape the information off of each page
for idx in range(len(listings_df)):
    
    # Alias the hrefs and add with the original url to get the link
    link = listings_df["url"][idx]
    
    # Use links with Selenium and start scraping the content off of the webpages
    driver.get(link)
    
    # Find out if the tags "tr" are present as they contain most of the features before 10 seconds
    tag_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tr"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(tag_present)
    
    # Find the property size and clean the text
    try:
        unclean_property_size = driver.find_element_by_class_name("listingheader").text
        clean_property_size = unclean_property_size.replace("\n", " ")
        property_size = next(iter(re.findall(r'[0-9]{3,4}[ ][S][q][f][t]', 
                                             clean_property_size)), None).replace(" Sqft", "")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    
    # Find the description and clean the text
    try:
        description = driver.find_element_by_class_name("listingoverview").text
        description = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', "", description)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    
    # Get the <tr> tags to get each individual line of information that is wanted
    body_lines = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    
    # Loop through each line that is found in the tags and alias the values accordingly
    for idx in range(len(body_lines)):
        # Convert all to strings first
        str_body_lines = str(body_lines[idx].text)
        # Split the values from its features on the website
        split_body_lines = str_body_lines.split("\n")
        
        # Listing Price
        if split_body_lines[0].lower() == "list price":
            unclean_list_price = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Number of Bedrooms
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "bedrooms":
            num_bedrooms = int(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Number of Bathrooms
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "bathrooms":
            num_bathrooms = int(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Property Type
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "property type":
            property_type = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Lot Size
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "lot size":
            unclean_lot_size = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Year Built
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "year built":
            unclean_year_built = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Title/type of property ownership
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "title":
            title = str(split_body_lines[1])
            
        # Style of the Property
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "style":
            style = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Features
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "features":
            the_features = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Amenities found in/around the property
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "amenities":
            the_amenities = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Appliances
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "appliances":
            the_appliances = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Community/neighbourhood the property is situated in
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "community":
            community = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Days on the REW website
        elif split_body_lines[0] == "days on rew":
            unclean_days_on_website = str(split_body_lines[1])
        
        # Pass if the line is none of the above choices
        else:
            continue
    
    # Remove any punctuation and unwanted strings in features being extracted
    try:
        list_price = re.sub(r'[^\d]', "", unclean_list_price)
    except:
        list_price == None
    
    try:
        year_built = next(iter(re.findall(r'[0-9]{4}', unclean_year_built)), None)
    except:
        year_built == None
    
    try:
        days_on_website = re.sub(r'[^\d]', "", unclean_days_on_website)
    except:
        days_on_website == None
        
    try:
        lot_size = next(iter(re.findall(r'[0-9]{4}', unclean_lot_size)), None)
        lot_size = int(lot_size)
    except:
        lot_size == 0
    
    # Append all of the values to the respective arrays
    property_sizes.append(property_size)
    descriptions.append(description)
    list_prices.append(int(list_price))
    bedrooms.append(num_bedrooms)
    bathrooms.append(num_bathrooms)
    property_types.append(property_type)
    lot_sizes.append(lot_size)
    years_built.append(int(year_built))
    titles.append(title)
    styles.append(style)
    features.append(the_features)
    amenities.append(the_amenities)
    appliances.append(the_appliances)
    communities.append(community)
    days_on_rew.append(int(days_on_website))
```

Comment: First of all: what is `listings_df' here?

Comment: Sorry that could have been more clear. 'listings_df' is my dataframe containing each real estate address and the respective URLs to view the pages.